# how do I get a product attribute

Tags: product-attribute

I have product attribute, tvitemid, but I can't seem to get it's value. below is the code. I tried 4 different methods.

I created the attribute as global in the product admin and I can see values in the admin.

I have read similar questions but it still does not work for me.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($products as $product){

    //works
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    echo "sku = $sku  ";


    //from here down, I get no results
    $tvitemid1 = $product->getTvitemid();
    echo " tvitemid1 = $tvitemid1 ";

    $tvitemid2 = $product->getAttributeText('tvitemid');
    echo " tvitemid2 = $tvitemid2 ";

    $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    $tvitemid3 = $prod->getAttributeText('tvitemid');
    echo " tvitemid3 = $tvitemid3 ";

    $tvitemid4 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getProductId())->getData('tvitemid');
    echo " tvitemid4 = $tvitemid4 \n";

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Load your collection like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('vitemid');
```

Also rebuild your indexes in `System->Index Management`.

You can get the attribute value like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product){
    $value = $product->getAttributeText('tvitemid'); //if the attribute is dropdown or multiselect and you need the label.
    //or
    $value = $product->getTvitemid(); //for simple text attribute.
}
```

Comment: What code do I use to get the value? What code would I use to change the value

Comment: @sdfor. See my update

Comment: This is Right Way. :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not working because you have to load the product object again. Because You fetch the data form Collection object and they give you just basic values and If you want to fetch that Custom value you have to load the data again.

Try Simple One

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($products as $product){
    //works
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    echo "sku = $sku  ";
    $prod=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    echo $prod->getAttributeText('tvitemid');
}
?>
```

Comment: This works but it's a performance killer. Loading entities inside a `foreach` is not recommended.

Comment: Yes @Marius I agree with you Its take too Much time. but I gave answer as per question asked.

Comment: I'm not questioning the validity of the answer. Like I said 'It works'. I just don't recommend it. It's just my opinion

Comment: this does not work for me, the return value is empty.

Comment: @Marius It's ok :)

Comment: @sdfor That will defiantly work. you miss some thing

Comment: it is in a foreach loop because I need to change all the values. It's a one time program.

Comment: I don't know, it still does not return values. The attribute scope is global, TextField, unique value yes, required no, validation no, apply to all products, all front end values no. I entered and can see values in the admin panel.

Comment: set Visible on Product View Page on Front-end to Yes.

Comment: that makes no difference. I must have something else wrong.

Comment: "tvitemid" is your attribute code ? please check  in manage attribute. also print the prod object and check you got that value or not? Also check this attribute will assign to the attribute set or not and if assign then you select the value or not?

Comment: it works with  echo $prod->getData("tvitemid");  thanks

Comment: Yes If you have Textbox then This is also work. and if you want to access from the select box then this will work :)

Comment: although if there is no value for tvitemid, it returns the last one. odd.

Comment: it will not return last but it will return zero index value which you have provide in Manage attribute. Because Zero index is bydefault selected so

Answer (score 0):

Attribute settings are OK? Show on front-end needs to be set to YES and then you can echo/show the attribute.

i use this for sku: `<?php echo nl2br($_product->getSku()) ?>` or this for my custom attribute: `<?php echo $_product->getData('procent'); ?>`